# Python-Mysql: Multiple attempts to connect - Best Practice

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection

I have following database connection code, initially I didn't have the while loop for multiple attempts but then I thought its better that I do multiple attempts before really fail it. My question is, what is the best way to accomplish this? Should I be using a timmer? and do some sleep prior to attempting again?

```
    while connect_attempts < 3:
        try:
            # dbname cann't have hyphen but host name can'
            db_name = self.language.replace('-','_') + 'db'
            print 'Connecting to DB ' + db_name
            logging.info("Connecting to Toolserver MySql Db: " + db_name)
            self.dbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(
                db=db_name,
                host=self.language + "someserver_name.org",
                read_default_file=os.path.expanduser("~/.my.cnf"))
            logging.info("Connection Successful: " + str(self.dbConnection))
            self.dbCursor = self.dbConnection.cursor(cursors.DictCursor)
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            logging.error("Unable to establish connection MySQL ERROR - attempt-" + str(connect_attempt), e.value)
            connect_attempts += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the default parameter is no time-out as indicated [here](http://structure.usc.edu/mysqldb/MySQLdb-3.html)

You can pass a parameter to set a timeout, eg. 10 seconds, after which this connection
will be dropped, and another attempt would be made to establish a connection.

Comment: A link to the original source is preferable: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Sumeet, you should set a timeout when calling `MySQLdb.connect()`. But the connection also could fail for many other reasons (e.g. the server immediately rejects the connection because it is too busy, or it is in some maintenance mode -- not real-life examples, just imagine)

Your own loop should include a short delay too. I would delay execution by a few seconds in your exception handler.